# mongo db Aggregation with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongodb and i am using node.js for making aggregation query to mongo db .My query looks like this :

```
db.orders.aggregate([
                 {$match:{status:"A"}},
                 {$group:{_id:"$cust_id",total:{$sum:"$amount"}}}])
```

My query is whether :

1. The match stage of this pipeline will run on my mongod shards
2. The group by stage will run on mongos /node.js(application) layer
       or on the mongod layer /database server .

Any insight into the internals of the aggregation pipleine in the context of node.js would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is: It depends.

First, it depends on your MongoDB version. And secondly, it also depends on your sharding key configuration. The [documentation on the aggregation framework for MongoDB v3.4 in conjunction with sharded collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/core/aggregation-pipeline-sharded-collections/) is not exactly exhaustive on this topic. However, it clearly states:

If the pipeline starts with an exact $match on a shard key, the entire pipeline runs on the matching shard only. Previously, the pipeline would have been split, and the work of merging it would have to be done on the primary shard.

> For aggregation operations that must run on multiple shards, if the
>   operations do not require running on the database’s primary shard,
>   these operations will route the results to a random shard to merge the
>   results to avoid overloading the primary shard for that database. The
>   $out stage and the $lookup stage require running on the database’s
>   primary shard.

The most interesting statement on this site, however, is probably this one:

> To see how the pipeline was split, include the explain option in the
>   db.collection.aggregate() method.

This way, you can find out yourself what your specific situation looks like.